# How can I look for 2 specific file names (Instead of FILENAME*) using a ListPattern method?

Tags: c#, chilkat

I'm rewriting a program that uses Chilkat's FTP class to connect to and then search a remote folder for specific file names...and then so on...

Specifically, I'm using a string {get; set;} to list files that contain a specific abbreviation.

the variable and string method read like..

```
varname.ListPattern = "FAST*";
```

This says listen for all files that begin with the "FAST" abbreviation. I've seen patterns like this used in other applications so I'm sure it's common to change the patter like "*.txt" for example.

I want to know if there is a way to listen for 2 specific file names ... something like "FASTBILL & FASTCOLL".. but I don't know what type of syntax to use for 2 specific file names instead of looping through all with a common abbreviation.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

> string patternAbbreviation = "FAST";
>
> var list = < get all filenames as text and place it in this list >
>
> var resultList = list.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.Contains(patternAbbreviation); });

process the *resultlist* via foreach

The list will contain all the filenames that contains the "FAST" abbreviation.